# Onchange event for multiple dropdowns issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<form>
<select id="List_22" >
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="1">Oil</option>
  <option value="2">Gas</option>  
  <option value="3">Power</option>
</select>
<form>
```

I want to launch a function upon dropdown change, so this works fine:

```
document.getElementById("List_22").onchange = function() {...
```

I however have multiple dropdowns that should all use the same function. I have tried to use the below wildcard but it does not work

```
document.getElementById("[id^=L]").onchange = function() {
```

What am I doing wrong? I am going slightly barmy. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: not able to use `.querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: You can use `$('select').change(function(){ ...`

Comment: Your code above will look for something that matches `id="[id^=L]"`.  Either use `getElementByTagName` or jQuery as the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('form select').on('change', function(){

    // Your code here
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `document.getElementById` looks for an exact ID match for a single element, so it doesn't support attribute selectors and nor does it return multiple elements.

In plain old JavaScript you can use `document.querySelectorAll` which supports CSS selectors, and the attribute selector. Note that this isn't supported before IE8.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=L]');
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    list[i].onchange = function(){
        // do something on change....
    };
}
```

Or since you have jQuery tagged, a jQuery version:

```
$('[id^=L]').change(function(){
    // do something on change....
});
```

Side note: In both cases, I would prefer to make the attribute selector more specific such as `select[id^=List_]`.

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript, you could do this generic search which should work in every browser and no need to regular expressions.

```
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
    item;

for (var i = 0, count = dropdowns.length; i < count; i++) {
    item = dropdowns[i];
    if (item.id && item.id.indexOf("List_") == 0) {
        item.onchange = function () {
            alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
        };
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq9nb/

Answer (score 0):

Best procedure for cases like this would be, to add a common class to all the dropdowns for which you want to call the function on change. For ex: add 'trigger-change' class for all your required dropdowns. Then below bind event should work perfect for you.

```
$('form select.trigger-change').on('change', function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

This way, you can choose the dropdowns for which you want to trigger a change event funciton and you can also have dropdowns which are not triggering the change event functions.

Hope this helps :)